# How to keep memory empty? Android

Tags: android, memory

My app has two 'heavy' fragments. When i move between them everytime allocate memory ~ 40mb. Meanwhile they haven't large bitmaps or something like that. And every time garbage collector free a little part of allocated memory ~10mb . My question what have i do to prevent allocate memory or free it?

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    onCreateCreator();
    name_text = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.info_title);
    artist_text = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.info_artist);
    info_duration = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.info_duration);
    crossfade_duration = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.crossfade_duration_text);
    crossfade_duration.setOnClickListener(this);
    increase_duration = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.increase_duration_text);
    increase_duration.setOnClickListener(this);
    fading_duration = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fading_duration_text);

    crossfade_switch = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.crossfade_switch);
    crossfade_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
                fading_switch.setChecked(false);
            }
            fading_switch.setEnabled(b);
        }
    });

    fading_switch = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.fading_switch);
    increase_switch = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.increase_switch);

    save = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    save_to_playlist = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.save_to_playlist);
    save_to_playlist.setOnClickListener(this);

    cover = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.info_cover);

    skip = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.skip_layout);
    skip.setOnClickListener(this);
    if (MODE == MODE_SINGLE) {
        skip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fill(track);
    }
    else {
        skip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fill(tracks.get(0));
    }
}

private void fill(Track track){

    this.track = track;
    cover.setImageBitmap(default_cover);
    int end_millis = Integer.valueOf(Settings.getMetadata(track.getPath(), MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
    name_text.setText(track.getName());
    artist_text.setText(track.getArtist());
    info_duration.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.info_duration) + ": " + Settings.getUserInterfaceDuration(end_millis, true, false));
    if (task != null) task.cancel(true);
    task = new MyTask(cover);
    task.execute(track);

    crossfade_duration.setText(String.valueOf(Settings.CROSSFADE_START));
    fading_duration.setText(String.valueOf(Settings.CROSSFADE_START));
    increase_duration.setText("0");
    fading_switch.setEnabled(false);

    fading_switch.setChecked(track.isFading());

    if (track.isMegamixTrack()){
        if (track.getCrossfadeDuration() > 1000){
            crossfade_switch.setChecked(true);
            crossfade_duration.setText(String.valueOf(track.getCrossfadeDuration()));
            fading_duration.setText(String.valueOf(track.getCrossfadeDuration()));
        }
        if (track.getIncrease() > 0){
            increase_switch.setChecked(true);
            increase_duration.setText(String.valueOf(track.getIncrease()));
        }
    } else{
        crossfade_switch.setChecked(false);
        increase_switch.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt you really need such a huge amount of memory every time, so you need to refactor your app thinking about memory usage and releasing it when no need.

Comment: Release what? Application or views maybe?

Comment: Without any code or precise description we cannot answer more. I doubt your fragments use 40MB only with views... What inside a 40MB fragment? Think about it.

Comment: Yeah, it only views. How can i free this memory? maybe set them as null, do you know any ways?)

Comment: I told you, except if you give us your code, we cannot answer further.

Comment: Oh, i think i got solution. Every time i created new fragment object! Now i tried create it one time a set it as static. So now i use only one object every time and garbage collector collect waste memory.

Comment: Holding a UI object such as a fragment or view in a static reference can lead to memory leaks.  For example if the fragment is destroyed and recreated, you could be holding onto the old one still.